# How to find & remove twitter spambot?

Tags: windows, malware, spam

Sometimes i can see that i've "retweeted" some tweets , that i actually didn't. And all of them spam to some gaming & pharma websites. I've got windows 7 64bit, norton internet security , using chrome for web browsing. 
Have tried using malwarebytes, spyware doctor & etc.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This sounds more like malware.  I assume you have tried to change your information to prevent the malicious user from continued access to your account?

Answer (score 3):

Have you authorized any Apps under https://twitter.com/settings/applications ?

Comment: Only twitter for blackberry. Shoud i revoke access ?

Comment: You could try if revoking access stops the spam.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that someone has guessed the password to your account on twitter, and may be directly accessing it.  Try changing the password to something significantly difficult and see what that does for you.

Comment: revoked access, changed password . Still happens :(

Comment: Try changing the password again from a totally different computer.  I'm just eliminating keystroke loggers here.

Answer (score 2):

You could have been infected by the [LilyJade worm](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/05/facebook-takes-aim-at-cross-browser-lilyjade-worm/) which is known to spam social networking websites. Check your apps [on twitter](https://twitter.com/settings/applications) and if none of that works then try changing your password.

Comment: i'm not saving passwords , no cookies , https only , opendns. No apps